# Ext JS 3 to Ext JS 4 migration issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

I want to migrate code based on Ext JS 3 to Ext JS 4.
There is class [Ext.Updater](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/?class=Ext.Updater) in Ext JS 3, and I can not find such functionality in Ext JS 4. Maybe someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually a successful migration is never promised by officially. But if you still want to migrate, you can follow [this guide](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/upgrade).

Answer (score -1):

EXT 4.x has Ext.ElementLoader which has similar capabilities to update the element using ajax calls.
Take a look at it.

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/docs/index.html#!/api/Ext.ElementLoader

Hope this is what you were looking for.